# Scrollable ListPicker items list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, popup, listpicker

I have a Popup control in my application. In this popup I use a ListPicker object to choose
the proper item. If the list of items if quite small, everything works fine, but, however, if the list items number is big, the list of items is shown at a new page somewhere at the background. That's the native behavior for **ExpansionMode.FullScreenOnly** of ListPicker, but I can't use it that way.

Is there a way to make a list of items scrollable to save the ListPicker behaviour of **ExpansionAllowed** style?

If not, is there a similar control in Windows Phone, that allows to create a drop-down menu in that style?

---

Right, let me show the difference:

1) That's how it should work, the number of elements is quite low, there are only four of them. When I click at the item (item has a name 2012-12-17) a list of items is shown in drop-down menu.

[image]

2) That's the problem one. The number of items is high, there are more than ten. When I click at the current item, the drop-down menu isn't shown in this popup, instead it's shown at the new page (could be seen in background). But that breaks all my logic, I can't even choose another element(can't click on it, because you can't click on page when popup is opened).

[image]

Can anyone propose a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListPicker control seems to be useless, as I couldn't find out how to solve this problem.

The solution will be to use different control, for example ListBox, which is scrollable by default. (will be similar to [Scrolling ContextMenu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352095/scrolling-contextmenu-items) question solution) That will be differ from the UI-style I wanted, but it will work.